# Apply same function in data-rel order

Tags: jquery, html, delay, auto-increment

I have multiple objects that I want to apply a .`delay()` and `.fadeIn()` function but the function needs to be applied in the order of the data-rel numbers.

Also, I need the delay to increase by 100 for each object...

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/shvu07s2/3/) worksheet.

What I would need it the
`data-rel="1"` to fadeIn with delay 0
`data-rel="2"` to fadeIn with delay 100
`data-rel="3"` to fadeIn with delay 200

HTML:

```
<div class="fadein">
    <p class="me" data-rel="1">1</p>
    <p class="me" data-rel="3">2</p>
    <p class="me" data-rel="2">3</p>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$( ".me" ).hide();

  $( ".me" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).delay(0).fadeIn(500);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute the `delay` depending on the value in `rel`

```
$(".me").each(function () {
    var el = $(this),
        rel = el.data("rel"),
        delay = (rel - 1) * 100;

    el.delay(delay).fadeIn(500);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3aohm4b/)

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
$( ".me" ).hide();
var waiter = 0;
  $( ".me" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).delay(waiter).fadeIn(500);
      waiter += 100;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shvu07s2/4/

EDIT:

```
$( ".me" ).hide();
var waiter = 0;
  $( ".me" ).each(function() {
      waiter = $(this).attr('data-rel')*1000-1000;
    $( this ).delay(waiter).fadeIn(500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shvu07s2/8/

Comment: Nope it doesn't :) It would work if I didn't need it to increase the delay according to the data-rel number. Thanks for trying :D

Answer (score 1):

Shortest :)

```
$( ".me" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).delay(100*$(this).attr("data-rel")).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: True, and it is working properly, thanks for the example. +1 for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Using your data values you can do this:

```
$( ".me" ).hide();

  $( ".me" ).each(function() {
    var $this = $( this ),
        relval = $this.data('rel');  

    $this.delay(0 + relval).fadeIn(500);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shvu07s2/7/

Comment: Well this works, kida, but what I needed (and got from @Andreas) is and auto increment by 100 of the delay and the data-rel to give only the order...placing the delay inside the data-rel will work for only a few objects but if you have a lot of them, it will get annoying. Thanks thought, +1 for trying and the example.